# SyntaxError: invalid syntax Selenium

Tags: python

```
$ python script.py 
  File "script.py", line 33
    elem = browser.find_element_by_name("//*[@id="search"]") 
                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I thought it was an error due to the Xpath, but it seems correct.
The other Xpath are different, much longer but I do not think change anything

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_name("//*[@id="search"]")
```

I would like to eliminate this error, but I am wondering in the void, I believe it is resolved by setting in a different way the Xpath

HTML:

```
<input id="search" type="search" tabindex="1" name="term"      placeholder="Search" class="main-search rounded form-control input-lg  clearable" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" dir="auto" autocapitalize="none" value="">
```

Comment: Would `find_element_by_id("search")` not help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `"`, or use `'`.

Option 1:

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_name("//*[@id=\"search\"]")
```

Option 2:

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_name('//*[@id="search"]')
```

Update:

Now that you've solved the escaping issue, if you are trying to find an element by its id, try using:

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_id('search')
```

Comment: I try both option but i get this error: elenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given css selector expression "[name="//*[@id="search"]"]" is invalid: InvalidSelectorError: '[name="//*[@id="search"]"]' is not a valid selector: "[name="//*[@id="search"]"]"         I update on my question the HTML

Comment: Ok. That's a different (new) question. try using `find_element_by_id` instead of `find_element_by_name`.

Comment: ah sorry... I optain the same error

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape your quotes or use different quotes:

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_name('//*[@id="search"]')
```

Comment: Same as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53946178/3091398)